# framer-motion, styled-components and nextjs Link component not animating

Tags: next.js, styled-components, framer-motion

when creating a `framer-motion` `styled-component` link ``` styled(motion.a)``; ```, I cannot trigger an animation on it if it is the child of a nextjs `Link` component.

nextjs `Link` docs:

> If the child of Link is a function component, in addition to using
> passHref, you must wrap the component in React.forwardRef

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-function-component

the sandbox represents 3 cases, only one triggers an animation, the one where I do not pass the ref attribute to the styled motion link component

https://codesandbox.io/s/motion-link-does-not-animate-if-child-of-nextjs-link-component-q0by8?file=/pages/index.js

Is this the expected behavior, if so please could you explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

issue is fixed in `framer-motion 4.1.16`